# Where do I go wrong? (cartesian form of parametric eq.)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, parametric

Basic stuff but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Much appreciated if someone could check through my working to see where I misstep!

$$x(t)=t+\frac{1}{t}, y(t)=1-\frac{1}{t}$$

So: $xt-1=t^2\,\,\,\,(1)$ $\,\,\,\,\,1-yt=t \,\,\,(2)$

$\implies xt-1=1-2yt+(yt)^2$

$t(x+2y)-2=(yt)^2 \implies x+2y=yt+\frac{2}{t}$ Note: $\frac{1}{t}=x-t$ so

$x+2y=yt+2(x-t)=t(y-2)+2x$

$$\therefore t=\frac{2y-x}{y-2}$$

Sub into $(2)$ to get: $1-y(\frac{2y-x}{y-2})=\frac{2y-x}{y-2}$.

simplifying the expression is easy from there, but plotting the parametric curve at this point and comparing it to the plot of the above cartesian expression, I'm obviously wrong at this point. My question: where's the mistake(s)? Apologies for messy working.

Comment: It should be $x + 2y = y^2t + \frac{2}{t}$.

Comment: oh jesus. I went through the algebra like 5 times and missed that every time. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y = 1 - \frac{1}{t} \implies yt= t - 1 \implies t-yt=1$$ so what you labelled as (2) is incorrect.

Comment: And actually you could just straight away find that $t=\frac{1}{1-y}$, which moves things along pretty quickly. This is embarrassing, I need some sleep.

Comment: True, I just tried to get it close to the form in which you wrote it so you could see the mistake more easily. But yes indeed, sometimes it's best to get some sleep! :)